# 4 PHP scripts deleting files and folders older than 21 days with specified extension and prefix

Tags: php

I'm trying to create 4 scripts which will make the fallowing tasks:

- SCRIPT 1 - Delete files older than 21 days with 'txt' extension
- SCRIPT 2 - Delete folders inside specified path older than 21 days
- SCRIPT 3 - Delete files inside specified path older than 21 days
- SCRIPT 4 - Delete files inside the folder and subfolders older than 21 days with prefix 'file_prefix'

Below is the code I found online. So I created 4 separate files like script1.php and so on, uploaded on my server and tried to fire them up. All I have returned is the code itself in the browser window, but files and folders are not deleted:( Hope you can help me on that.
Below I tried to adopt the code I found online and create 3 scripts. Unfortunately I have no idea how to create the 4th one as it will be more complicated.

I'm only a front end developer started to learn the PHP code basics...

`/***** SCRIPT 1 - Delete files older than 21 days with .txt extension *****/`

```
$days = 21;  
$path = './mypath/folder_with_txt_files/';  
$filetypes_to_delete = array("txt");  
    
if ($handle = opendir($path))  
{   
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))  
    {  
        if (is_file($path.$file))  
        {  
            $file_info = pathinfo($path.$file);  
            if (isset($file_info['extension']) && in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), $filetypes_to_delete))  
            {  
                if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
                {  
                    unlink($path.$file);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

`/***** SCRIPT 2 - Delete folders older than 21 days *****/`

```
$days = 21;  
$path = './mypath/folders_to_delete/';  
  
if ($handle = opendir($path))  
{   
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))  
    {   
        if (is_dir($path.$file))  
        {    
            if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
            {  
                unlink($path.$file);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

`/***** SCRIPT 3 - Delete files older than 21 days *****/`

```
$days = 21;  
$path = '/mypath/folder_with_files_to_delete';  
  
if ($handle = opendir($path))  
{   
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))  
    {   
        if (is_file($path.$file))  
        {    
            if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
            {  
                unlink($path.$file);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

`/***** SCRIPT 4 - Delete files inside the folder and subfolders older than 21 days with prefix 'file_prefix' *****/`

```
?
```

Comment: Run them in command line, not in a browser.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are there any error message shown? If not: would there be any if you used a higher error reporting level?

Comment: If it's displaying the php code in the browser, you may just need to add the <?php and ?> at the beginning and end of the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver tries hard to isolate its working from that of the
operating system, for evident security reasons.
The webserver itself normally runs under a very strict and limited user account.

For running maintenance scripts via the browser you need to undo these protections
and give the webserver permissions over more folders.

**This would be a very bad idea.**

You may however run these scripts from the command-line version of PHP,
meaning from the console. It would then have the same permissions
as inherited from the console.